# Virtualbox : mouse only working on part of the screen after I use the guest additions

Tags: virtualbox

I tried to set up a VM running on centos7, my host run on windows 10. After I add the guest additions, my mouse still doesn't work properly : if you look at the image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZRqq.jpg), the mouse work properly below the red line, and won't work on the rest of the screen. I found nothing related to that problem on Internet, so I'd be glad if you had any idea or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to press the [CTRL] key on the right hand side of the keyboard.

Then the mouse gets release back to you.